# The ages of A and B differ by 2 years....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The ages of A and B differ by 2 years. A's mother D is twice as old as A and B is twice as old as his sister C. The age of D and C differ by 40 years. Find the ages of A and B.

{Ans: 26yrs and 24 yrs}…

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A-B=2 \tag 1$$
$$D=2A\tag 2$$
$$B=2C \implies C=B/2 \tag 3$$
$$D-C=40\tag 4$$

$(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(4)$ yield

$$2A-B/2=40 \tag 5$$

Can you finish using $(1)$ and $(5)$?